# plugin shortcode output

Tags: plugins, shortcode, html

I have a plugin which uses this shortcode: `[daisy]`

And the html output of this shortcode is : `<a class="clickable">Click Here</a>`

Plugin is working perfect if I use the shortcode to trigger the plugin.
It works with this also:     `<?php echo do_shortcode('[daisy]'); ?>`

Normally it should work also with the `<a class="clickable">Click Here</a>`
 but it's not working, the link appears but if I click on it nothing happens.

I want to use the html output because my website is using a lot of javascript for displaying html content I cannot use php shortcodes inside javascript/jquery functions.

So, do you have any suggestions for this issue? 
Because I think the shortcode should work also with the html output which triggers that plugin (in my case is a contact form popup)
Thanks!
Later edit: This is the javascript which triggers the plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Init Plugin
    $(".clickable").contactpopup({
        'style' : '<?php echo $wp_cpup_theme; ?>',
        'bgcolor' : '<?php echo $wp_cpup_color; ?>',
        'formelement' : '#Form_PopContactUs',
        'effect' : '<?php echo $wp_cpup_effect; ?>',
        'header' : '<?php echo $wp_cpup_popup_title; ?>'
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this a plugin you wrote or one from someone else?

Comment: from someone else...

Comment: Can you please tell us what plugin it is? Most likely it doesn't work because the short code triggers some javascript to load, which doesn't happen when just using the HTML.

Comment: [this](http://themes.thevda.com/wordpress/contact-popup/) is the plugin, and yes I think it triggers some javascript, so is impossible to use just the html of the shortcode?

Comment: I've updated my post! Maybe now it's more relevant.

Comment: Does the plugin have a download page somewhere so I can look at the source?

Comment: Actually no, because is not free but I can post the source code if you want to take a look

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/kYDL4ekw) is the source code

Comment: Ugh, there is a _lot_ wrong with that plugin. In this case, with the way it is built, you will not be able to use it with just the HTML, not unless you rewrite half the plugin to begin with. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the plugin file and find where the function add_shortcode('daisy','someotherfunction'); is, then you could simply call that function that the shortcode is pointing too.

This code could be placed as follows in a plugin or the functions.php file of your theme:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'daisy_fun' );

function daisy_fun(){
?>
        <script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
                  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        var daisyLink = '<?php echo wp_contact_popup_short_code_handler(); ?>';
                  });
        </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know this is impossible, because you cannot put php function inside jquery because php is a server-side language

Comment: You should always use jQuery in noConflict mode when using it in WordPress. So use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`, otherwise it will result in conflicts.

Comment: In regards to using PHP in JS, yes, you can do it, but only if the JS is placed inline within a PHP file.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how can I do this in my scenario? Thank you !

Comment: I changed the $ into jQuery.  But I do want to note that when using a $, I always surround my script with (function ($) {})(jQuery);

Comment: I have something like this : `add_shortcode("daisy", "wp_contact_popup_short_code_handler");
` so,  I create the jquery var daisylink =  (what exactly I need to put here?)

Comment: [this](http://pastebin.com/kYDL4ekw) is the source code for the plugin

Comment: Just made an edit; I hope it works for you.